# Should the tags [rpg] and [rpgle] be merged?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

According to the tag wiki for each tag, [rpgle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rpgle) is supposed to be used for ILE RPG on IBM i, whereas [rpg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rpg) is supposed to be used for OPM RPG/400 and all other RPG implementations (RPG on non-IBM platforms and other IBM platforms). However, in practice, it looks like that advice is very often not being followed – observe the number of questions tagged with both tags, when it seems the question is actually about ILE RPG. Indeed, I think most people who tag their question with plain [rpg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rpg) are actually asking about ILE RPG – in 2021, it is significantly more likely that someone will be asking a question about ILE RPG and tag it as [rpg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rpg) just because they didn't read the tag wiki, then that someone would actually be asking a question specifically about OPM RPG/400 or some other RPG implementation. Given this reality, is there really any use in keeping the two separate tags? I suspect not.

I think making [rpgle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rpgle) the main tag, and [rpg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rpg) the synonym, might have the advantage of reducing people mistakenly using [rpg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rpg) for questions about role-playing games, even if allowing non-ILE RPG questions in the scope of [rpgle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rpgle) would technically be a misnomer.

Comment: *"I think making rpgle the main tag, and rpg the synonym, might have the advantage of reducing people mistakenly using rpg for questions about role-playing games"* I find this _highly_ unlikely, because _nobody looks at synonyms when using a tag_

Comment: @Nick Correct, but if I tag a question with a synonym, won't the tag then get replaced by the main tag on display? Seeing something inappropriate might trigger the user to investigate

Comment: Ehhhh, I'm not entirely sure, more just food for thought :), synonyms are a weird part of stack